# Unable to use Stepper in SwiftUI Xcode 12

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

The following code does not compile, but I believe it should.

```
Stepper("Number of Pages", value: $numberOfPages, in: 3 ..< 6)
```

The error I get is this. It is highlighting the range.

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Range<Int>' to expected argument type 'ClosedRange<String>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numberOfPages` should be an `Int`, and you need to use a `ClosedRange` `3 ... 5` instead of a half-open one `3 ..< 6`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var numberOfPages = 3
    
    var body: some View {
        Stepper("Number of Pages: \(numberOfPages)", value: $numberOfPages, in: 3 ... 5)
    }
}
```